# split method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array. Within it I have 2 names. I want to pick only the surname by a split function, but it is not working. I have separated first name and last name using an underscore.

```
function spt (){
    var m= new Array('jitender_chand','shashi_cant')

    var j= m.split('_');

    document.getElementById('add').innerHTML=j;

    }
<body>
<input type="text" value="hii" id="jitender" />
<input type="button" onclick="spt()" />

<div id="add" ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look into the following code.Hope this helps you:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input type="text" value="hii" id="jitender" />
<input type="button" value="Click me to split" onclick="spt()" />
<div id="add" ></div>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
function spt (){
    var m= new Array('jitender_chand','shashi_cant');
    for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    var j= m[i].split('_')[1];       
    document.getElementById('add').innerHTML=
        document.getElementById('add').innerHTML + "," + j;
    }   
}
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/C8h9K/

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
var m = new Array('jitender_chand','shashi_cant')
var splitted = m[0].split("_")[1]; //for jitender_chand
//and use m[1].split("_")[1]; //for other name
alert(splitted);
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML=splitted;
```

OR if you want ta add surnames in an array, then:

```
var m = new Array('jitender_chand','shashi_cant');
var surname = [];
for(var s = 0; s < m.length; s++) {
  surname.push(m[s].split("_")[1]);
}
console.log(surname);
//if you want to join surnames, then
var joinedSurnames = surname.join(",");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This. `split` is a method of the `String` class, not the `Array` class. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split for more information )

Comment: its working but i want add last name of names in one click how does we do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you can't call split on an array.

```
var j = new Array()
for (var i in m) {
    j.push(m[i].split('_'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript 1.6 or later, you can use Array's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to iterate over each member of the array and split the member (String) on underscore:

```
var m = ["jitender_chand", "shashi_cant"];
var j = m.map(function (name){
  return name.split("_")[1];
});

document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = j;
```